# xslt manipulation using C#

Tags: c#, xslt

I have a parent xslt that contains 100 fields elements(nested fields are present). Now i need to create a child xslt that contains 50 fields(based on an excel file) retaining the same structure as the parent, removing a few unwanted fields fron the parent. 
Any input on how do i proceed.

Comment: Any chance you could give us a more illustrative example?

Comment: Sample XML Parent: <ABCD>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>3</c>
  <d>4</d>
</ABCD>          Required XML Child : <ABCD>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
</ABCD>------ the child xml should have the nodes(<a>, <b>) present in an excel file.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. What does your parent XSLT look like?

Comment: Forget about the xslt. If i can find a way to convert the parent xml as shown above then to the child xml, then i can repeat that for xslt.

Comment: Have you already figured out how to get the list of fields from an Excel file, or is that part of the question you're asking?

Comment: yes, thats the part i am preety much asking. Again, once i do that how do i retain them in my parent xml and removet the unwanted ones in a new xml.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already figured out how to populate an array (or other collection) with the list of fields to remove, you should be able to do something like this:

```
string[] fields = new string[] { "c", "d" };
// In actuality, the assumption is that your XmlDocument is loaded some other way
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<ABCD> <a>1</a> <b>2</b> <c>3</c> <d>4</d> </ABCD>");

string xpath = "//*[" + fields.Select(v => "self::" + v)
                              .Aggregate((a, b) => a + " or " + b) 
                      + "]";
List<XPathNavigator> nodes = document.CreateNavigator().Select(xpath).Cast<XPathNavigator>().ToList();
foreach (XPathNavigator node in nodes)
{
    node.DeleteSelf();
}

string resultDoc = document.OuterXml;
```

Comment: string xpath = "//*[" + fields.Select(v => "self::" + v)
                              .Aggregate((a, b) => a + " or " + b) 
                      + "]";
what does this do? am unable to understand it.

Comment: It uses the list of fields to produce an XPath to locate all fields with those names.  So in the example, this would produce the XPath `//*[self::c or self::d]`.